# Time Series: testing significance

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

Assume we follow a single companies stock over several years. This stock has a steady upward trend over the years we are recording its value. Then in the current year it takes a hard downward trend in the year. Is there a way I can test for the significance of this that would indicate a break in the overall trend of the stock, to indicate the upward trend is no longer relevant?

Comment: That seems ARCH.

Comment: As you might imagine, this is a common question. Useful keywords for searching this site (and others) are "changepoint" and "structural change."